# SQL Server 2014 installation - Receiving "Could not find the Database Engine startup handle."

Tags: sql-server-2014

I'm trying to install a second instance on one of my servers and receiving an error at the end of the installation process that says "Could not find the Database Engine startup handle." I have tried uninstalling the failed instance and rebooting the server to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Which user are you running under? See also [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24364.sql-server-troubleshooting-could-not-find-database-engine-startup-handle-error-during-installation.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to go into the registry and enabling SSL and TLS (both client and server) protocols. The installation completed after that. Furthermore, if I disabled these protocols and restarted the SQL Server service, it would fail to start.